# how to set the use --enable-preview compile and run flags from gradle?

Tags: java, gradle, javac, java-14, preview-feature

[Looking](https://askubuntu.com/q/1240504/45156) to use `records` from Java 14 in a `gradle` build, but am getting:

```
thufir@dur:~/NetBeansProjects/FileWatcherHandler$ 
thufir@dur:~/NetBeansProjects/FileWatcherHandler$ gradle clean build

> Task :compileJava FAILED
/home/thufir/NetBeansProjects/FileWatcherHandler/src/main/java/net/bounceme/dur/files/FXOrder.java:3: error: records are a preview feature and are disabled by default.
public record FXOrder(int units) {}
       ^
  (use --enable-preview to enable records)
1 error

FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.

* What went wrong:
Execution failed for task ':compileJava'.
> Compilation failed; see the compiler error output for details.

* Try:
Run with --stacktrace option to get the stack trace. Run with --info or --debug option to get more log output. Run with --scan to get full insights.

* Get more help at https://help.gradle.org

BUILD FAILED in 641ms
2 actionable tasks: 1 executed, 1 up-to-date
thufir@dur:~/NetBeansProjects/FileWatcherHandler$
```

compiling with `javac` looks okay:

```
thufir@dur:~/java$ 
thufir@dur:~/java$ ls
FXOrder.java
thufir@dur:~/java$ 
thufir@dur:~/java$ cat FXOrder.java 

public record FXOrder(int units) {}
thufir@dur:~/java$ 
thufir@dur:~/java$ javac --enable-preview -source 14 FXOrder.java 
Note: FXOrder.java uses preview language features.
Note: Recompile with -Xlint:preview for details.
thufir@dur:~/java$ 
thufir@dur:~/java$ ls
FXOrder.class  FXOrder.java
thufir@dur:~/java$
```

how to set those compile options in the following build file:

```
/*
 * This file was generated by the Gradle 'init' task.
 *
 * This generated file contains a sample Java project to get you started.
 * For more details take a look at the Java Quickstart chapter in the Gradle
 * User Manual available at https://docs.gradle.org/6.4.1/userguide/tutorial_java_projects.html
 */

plugins {
    // Apply the java plugin to add support for Java
    id 'java'

    // Apply the application plugin to add support for building a CLI application.
    id 'application'
}

repositories {
    // Use jcenter for resolving dependencies.
    // You can declare any Maven/Ivy/file repository here.
    jcenter()
}

dependencies {
    // This dependency is used by the application.
    implementation 'com.google.guava:guava:28.2-jre'

    // Use TestNG framework, also requires calling test.useTestNG() below
    testImplementation 'org.testng:testng:7.1.1'
}

application {
    // Define the main class for the application.
//    mainClassName = 'FileWatcherHandler.App'
    mainClassName = 'net.bounceme.dur.files.App'


}

test {
    // Use TestNG for unit tests
    useTestNG()
}
```

java version:

```
thufir@dur:~/java$ 
thufir@dur:~/java$ gradle --version

------------------------------------------------------------
Gradle 6.4.1
------------------------------------------------------------

Build time:   2020-05-15 19:43:40 UTC
Revision:     1a04183c502614b5c80e33d603074e0b4a2777c5

Kotlin:       1.3.71
Groovy:       2.5.10
Ant:          Apache Ant(TM) version 1.10.7 compiled on September 1 2019
JVM:          14.0.1 (AdoptOpenJDK 14.0.1+7)
OS:           Linux 5.4.0-29-generic amd64

thufir@dur:~/java$ 
thufir@dur:~/java$ java --version
openjdk 14.0.1 2020-04-14
OpenJDK Runtime Environment AdoptOpenJDK (build 14.0.1+7)
OpenJDK 64-Bit Server VM AdoptOpenJDK (build 14.0.1+7, mixed mode, sharing)
thufir@dur:~/java$ 
thufir@dur:~/java$ javac --version
javac 14.0.1
thufir@dur:~/java$ 
thufir@dur:~/java$ which java
/home/thufir/.sdkman/candidates/java/current/bin/java
thufir@dur:~/java$
```

Answer (score 22, accepted):

To make this work you can modify the `compileJava` task and add this flag. Add this to your `build.gradle` :

```
compileJava {
    options.compilerArgs += ['--enable-preview']
}
```

This will make sure that your code will compile.

---

If you have other tasks which require compilation (for example `compileTestJava`) you can enable this flag for all tasks which have type `JavaCompile` :

```
tasks.withType(JavaCompile).all {
    options.compilerArgs += ['--enable-preview']
}
```

---

To enable this flag for test tasks you can do the following :

```
tasks.withType(Test).all {
    jvmArgs += '--enable-preview'
}
```

---

You also have to make sure to add this flag for the JVM that will run your code :

```
tasks.withType(JavaExec) {
    jvmArgs += '--enable-preview'
}
```

This is described in the corresponding [JEP](https://openjdk.java.net/jeps/12) :

> Developers who wish to use preview language features in their programs must explicitly enable them in the compiler and the runtime system

Comment: lol, yes, I just put an answer, but yes I think so.  I think you have to add the "source 14" option.

Answer (score 2):

adding this to the `build.gradle` file:

```
compileJava {
    options.warnings = false
    options.deprecation = false
    options.compilerArgs += ["-Xdoclint:none", "-Xlint:none", "-nowarn"]
    options.compilerArgs += ["-Xlint"]
    options.compilerArgs += ["--enable-preview"]
    options.compilerArgs += ["-source 14"]
    // options.compilerArgs << "-Xlint:unchecked" << "-Xlint:deprecation" 
}
```

also, the run option is required:

tasks.withType(JavaExec) {
    jvmArgs += '--enable-preview'
}

might fix, or is at least on the right track I think.

Comment: Worth noting that not all of these lines are necessary. Only `options.compilerArgs += ["--enable-preview"]`, `-source 14` and the run option are relevant.

Comment: I don't quite understand the `source 14` flag; the oracle blog specifies it as, I think, required...but is it?  I copied the above from another answer on stackoverflow but forgot to cite it.

Comment: @Clashsoft Within Intellij, when build is delegated to gradle, the launch of application from intellij is bombing unless this is added `tasks.withType(JavaExec) { jvmArgs += '--enable-preview' }`. Must be a bug in `IntelliJ IDEA 2020.2.1`